# visual studio c++ Serial Communication error

Tags: c++, unicode, serial-port, serial-communication

I'm going to do serial communication using visual studio c++.
However, when I try to use 'serialport port open', I get an error with the phrase L"//./com3
The error code is c2665, e0289.
Also, there is a possibility that the open port may change from time to time, so please help me to read the port automatically.

serialport.h

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

class SerialPort {
    public:
        HANDLE hComm;
        LPCWSTR COMport;
        DWORD dNoOFBytestoWrite;
        DWORD dNoOfBytesWritten;
        int BufSize;
        int Status;
        char* SerialBuffer;
        char* commandBuffer;
        DWORD NoBytesRead;


        SerialPort(LPCWSTR COMport, int setBaudRate, int setByteSize, char* commandBuffer, int BufSize);
        void Connect(LPCWSTR COMport, int setBaudRate, int setByteSize, char* commandBuffer);
        void sendCommand(int setBaudRate, int setByteSize, char* commandBuffer);
        void getData();
        
};
```

serial.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include "SerialPort.h"



SerialPort::SerialPort(LPCWSTR COM, int setBaudRate, int setByteSize, char* commandBuffer, int BufSize) {
    this->BufSize = BufSize;
    this->SerialBuffer = new char[BufSize];
    this->NoBytesRead = BufSize;
    Connect(COM, setBaudRate, setByteSize, commandBuffer);
}

void SerialPort::Connect(LPCWSTR COM, int setBaudRate, int setByteSize, char* commandBuffer) {
    this->COMport = COM;
    this->hComm = CreateFile(COM, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL); // (port name, read/write , no sharing , no security, open existing port only, non overlapped i/o , null for comm devices)

    if (this->hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        cout << "Error in Opening serial port" << endl;

    else {
        cout << "Opening serial port successful" << endl;
        sendCommand(setBaudRate, setByteSize, commandBuffer);
    }
}

void SerialPort::sendCommand(int setBaudRate, int setByteSize, char* commandBuffer) {
    this->commandBuffer = commandBuffer;
    this->dNoOFBytestoWrite = sizeof(commandBuffer);
    this->Status = WriteFile(hComm, commandBuffer, dNoOFBytestoWrite, &dNoOfBytesWritten, NULL);

    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = setBaudRate;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = setByteSize;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;

    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 10;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 10;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;

    if (this->Status)
        cout << "Command Successful" << endl;
    else
    {
        cout << "fail to Command" << endl;
    }
}

void SerialPort::getData() {
    ReadFile(this->hComm, &*this->SerialBuffer, this->BufSize, &this->NoBytesRead, NULL);
    
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SerialPort.h"


int main()
{

    SerialPort PortOpen( L"//./com3", CBR_115200, 8, "#or", 24);

    PortOpen.getData();
    PortOpen.getData();
    cout << PortOpen.SerialBuffer << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: My compiler says `cannot convert argument 4 from 'const char [4]' to 'char *'`. The problem being that `"#or"` is a constant, but the command buffer parameter is supposed to be non-const.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem. I want to make the port change actively. Can you help me?